# How can I access resources on a parent classpath using Spring 2.5.x?

Tags: java, spring, classpath, classloader

In my Websphere Portal environment, I'm trying to configure a bean that uses a resource found outside of the WAR (it's in some parent classpath for WAS).
I'm sure it's there because I can access it using the following:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/config/someProps.properties");
```

However, in my Spring applicationContext.xml, the following does not work:

```
<bean id="initBean" class="foo.PropInitializer">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:/config/someProps.properties"/>   
</bean>
```

If I remove the "classpath:", that doesn't help either.

Currently, I'm loading the Spring context using the ContextLoaderListener, but it seems that the parent classpath is not accessible/available to Spring.

Is there a way (using Spring config) to load the parent classpath as well?

Comment: Can we see the source for `foo.PropInitializer`, or least the fields and constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to (sort of) solve my question.

I ended up creating a factory class that I can use to load resources from the classpath:

```
<bean name="applicationConfig" class="foo.io.ResourceLoader">
    <constructor-arg value="/config/someProps.properties" />
</bean>
```

This was based off of an existing Spring class: `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource`

Unfortunately, the Spring class didn't quite work in my situation (I was experiencing some property ambiguity issues in the method I was passing the resulting bean into) which is why I created my own class that returned the exact type.

In any case, I expect that using Springs `ClassPathResource` will work in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass classpath*: instead of classpath:

```
<bean id="initBean" class="foo.PropInitializer">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath*:/config/someProps.properties"/>   
</bean>
```

You can find a more detailed explanation [here](http://www.carbonfive.com/community/archives/2007/05/using_classpath.html).

Comment: Sadly, I still get the following: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: classpath*:/config/someProps.properties